# let cons used both concretely and abstractly

Tags: haskell, let

I was doing this

```
reverseP x = pour x []
  where pour []    ans = ans
        pour (h:t) ans = pour t (h:ans)
```

where a parameter accumulator is better than the crude and costly version

```
reverse [] = []
reverse (h:t) = reverse t ++ [h]
```

But then I wanted to see if I could redo `reverseP` with `let` just as an exercise. I finally got this to work

```
reverseP2 x =
  let
    (t:ts) = x
    pour [] ans = ans
    pour (t:ts) ans = pour ts (t:ans)
  in pour x []
```

but I don't know why it's working. It's not realistic to expect to go on with Haskell writing working code that I don't understand, so I thought I'd better find out why this works. What's confusing me is that I've assigned the incoming `x` to the cons (Is this considered a tuple?) `(t:ts)`, but then I use `(t:ts)` in an "abstract" way as an argument to `pour` two lines later. Since it works, the recursions must indeed be breaking down the list correctly, i.e., the cons `(t:ts)` defined in the first line is being properly taken apart. Also confusing is how the `let` form above allows `pour` to be defined twice in the pattern matching way. I tried it with guards to keep it to only one `pour`, but then the `(t:ts)` did not properly break down -- part of why I'm surprised this works. So how can the same cons `(t:ts)` be both concrete and abstract, and how can `pour` recurse and behave pattern matching-wise inside the `let`? Also, could `reverseP2` be considered tail-recursive?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let’s try compiling this with warnings turned on:

```
Prelude> :set -Wall
Prelude> :{
Prelude| reverseP2 x =
Prelude|   let
Prelude|     (t:ts) = x
Prelude|     pour [] ans = ans
Prelude|     pour (t:ts) ans = pour ts (t:ans)
Prelude|   in pour x []
Prelude| :}

<interactive>:7:11: warning: [-Wname-shadowing]
    This binding for `t' shadows the existing binding
      bound at <interactive>:5:6

<interactive>:7:13: warning: [-Wname-shadowing]
    This binding for `ts' shadows the existing binding
      bound at <interactive>:5:8
```

What is this message saying? It says that the second definitions of `t` and `ts` are *shadowing* the first ones. That is, the two `t`s and the two `ts`s do not refer to the same value — the first `t:ts` is `x`, while the second `t:ts` refers to a parameter of `pour`. This is confusing! So let’s rename one of them:

```
reverseP2 x =
  let
    (t:ts) = x
    pour [] ans = ans
    pour (a:as) ans = pour as (a:ans)
  in pour x []
```

And in fact, this shows that you don’t even need `t` and `ts`, so let’s get rid of them:

```
reverseP2 x =
  let
    pour [] ans = ans
    pour (a:as) ans = pour as (a:ans)
  in pour x []
```

Finally, while I’m at it, I should note that for longer definitions such as that of `pour`, it is considered idiomatic to use a `where` block rather than `let`:

```
reverseP2 x = pour x []
  where
    pour [] ans = ans
    pour (a:as) ans = pour as (a:ans)
```

> I've assigned the incoming `x` to the cons (Is this considered a tuple?) `(t:ts)` …

No, this is not at all a tuple; this is a list. If it were a tuple, it would need to have type `(a, (a, (a,a)))` or similar; but as a list, it has type `[a]`.

> Also confusing is how the `let` form above allows `pour` to be defined twice in the pattern matching way.

But it’s not defining it twice! You have only one definition of `pour`, which depends on the input as follows: if the input is an empty list, `pour` returns `ans`, else it returns `pour as (a:ans)`.

> Also, could `reverseP2` be considered tail-recursive?

<s>I believe so</s> but generally speaking tail-recursion is considered unimportant in Haskell (see e.g. discussion starting [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/haskell/comments/leeth9/fibonacci_tail_recursion/gmg0pqv/?utm_source=reddit&utm_medium=web2x&context=3)).

**EDIT:** As @DanienWagner points out in the comments, `reverseP2` is not recursive at all! It is `pour` which is tail-recursive.

Comment: This was a perfect storm of my beginner-ness. I guess I was mesmerized by `let (x:xs) = [1,2,3,4] in x` giving me back `1` and just had to use it. So shadowing was going on. I thought so, but couldn't put my finger on it. I guess the main take-away was seemingly having `pour` defined twice, when it was actually just once, IOW, Haskell pattern matching lore.

Comment: `reverseP2` certainly isn't tail-recursive. It isn't even recursive. Now `pour` on the other hand...

Comment: @DanielWagner Ah, whoops, so it is! What an embarrassing mistake. I’ll correct it immediately.

Answer (score 3):

No wonder you're confused about `reverseP2`. The pattern-matching on `x` is redundant, because `t` and `ts` aren't being used in the `let` block. The `t` and `ts` variables that *are* used in the `let` block are the *more local* variables defined in the (partial) function definition `pour (t:ts) ans`. These `t` and `ts` [shadow](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable_shadowing) the other variables with the same names.

In fact, the pattern-matching expression `(t:ts) = x` is entirely redundant. You can simplify `reverseP2` to this:

```
reverseP2 x =
  let
    pour []     ans = ans
    pour (t:ts) ans = pour ts (t:ans)
  in pour x []
```

This, hopefully, makes it clearer that it just uses another syntax, but the same definition, as `reverseP`. Instead of giving the return value in the beginning of the function definition, you give the return value in the `in` block of `let/in`, and instead of defining auxiliary variables and functions in a `where` section, you define them in the `let` section.